# Как сделать дебаг с брекпоинтами для .so aндроид файлов в Unity Andorid?

Tags: c++, unity3d, unity3d-android

У меня есть Юнити Андроид проект который использует нативную `.so` либу. Не могу найти способ как можно сделать дебаг для `.so` файлов, это и есть вопрос.

Для примера когда я работаю с проектом Unity Windows то нет проблем открыть в Visual Studio свой `.dll` и прикрепить дебагер к процессу. Но в случае с `.so` файлами Android Studio не прикрепляет дебагер к процессу. То есть я могу нажать `Attach debugger to Android Process` потом нужн отметить `Show all processes` и выбираю нужный мне процесс, но ничего не происходит.

Подскажите как можно прикрепить дебагер к `.so` в моем случае?

Comment: если вы библиотеку собираете из исходников в проекте, и есть отладочная информация, то в андроид студии дебаггер работает "из коробки". пользовался недавно. правда до VS отладчику пока еще далеко, и он глючноват, но хоть как-то, но работает. если библиотека не ваша, она вероятнее всего собрана без отладочной информации, и символов отладочных у вас тоже в проекте не будет рядом с ней. найдите версию с отладочной информацией или соберите свою. и будет работать.

Comment: он работает из коробки даже без отладочной информации (хотя для откладки нативного кода такой режим малополезен)

Comment: @Yakov Библиотека моя и исходники естественно у меня. Делаю я ровно то, что написал в вопросе - запускаю приложение на телефоне (дебаг версия), открываю Студию нажисаю `Attach` , но те методы где я расчитываю получить брек поинт там дебагер не останавливается. Он просто как будто работает не в дебаге. Может я не так делаю? Как вы делаете?

Comment: @user7860670 что значит работает из коробки?. Делаю я ровно то, что написал в вопросе - запускаю приложение на телефоне (дебаг версия), открываю Студию нажисаю `Attach` , но те методы где я расчитываю получить брек поинт там дебагер не останавливается. Он просто как будто работает не в дебаге. то есть у меня не работает из коробки. Может я не так делаю? Как вы делаете?

Comment: сделай новый чистый проект типа нейтив Hello JNI поставь брейкпоинт в этой функции, запусти. проверь, что у тебя он срабатывает. может среда настроена не корректно, или плагины, или ндк не текущей версии и есть баг. если чистый проект заработает посмотри различия в окружении.

Comment: если проект собирается нормально, то в аттаче у тебя будет выбор какой тип отладчика подключить (java/native/dual/auto), если что-то собралось не так, то будет только ява. еще один нюанс, JNI обычно инициализируется или в статик секции класса, при первом обращении к статическому полю или при создании экземпляра класса, если у тебя исключение произойдет в момент загрузки библиотеки, и будет подавлено гденить в дебрях кода. то до брейкпоинта не дойдет. это надо в виду иметь обязательно. начни отладку с лоада библиотеки в ява коде. для начала. с места System.loadLibrary("libraryname");

Comment: там был нюанс с именами, нельзя использовать подчерки в имени. их отладчик AS не понимает.

Comment: @Yakov не совсем уверен, что понял тебя правильно. У меня есть либа .so которую я собираю в AS и добавляю ее в Plugins/Android в юнити и из скрипта юнити я обращаюсь к этой либе через методы DllExport (стандартное обращение). Ты говоришь создай чистый проект Hello JNI, создать где? В юнити? (вроде нет такой опции) значит в AS, но чем мне тогда это поможет? И у меня нет метода `System.loadLibrary` , так как я не использую JNI, как я сказал выше, я собираю либу .so нативную и юнити напрямую к ней обращается

Comment: Для проверки просто сделай в Android Studio новый проект с типом C++ Native. он тебе сделает проект Hello JNI, поставь брейкпонит в hello.cpp чтобы проверить, что отладчик вообще запускается у тебя на тестируемом устройстве. должно выглядеть так https://imgur.com/a/HKqk4YR

Comment: раз у тебя загрузка идет в другом месте, то AS не запускает отладчик для нативных библиотек автоматом. когда создается проект NDK при наличии библиотек у тебя отладчик(сейчас в 4.х LLDB) запускается отдельным процессом на **устройстве/эмуляторе**. Если его не запускает AS, то тебе придется это делать самостоятельно + как-то еще туда скопировать отладочные символы.

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/gdb